# Audacity could not find a safe place to store temporary files (installed via snap)

Tags: snap, audacity

In Ubuntu 18.04, Audacity is in a loop, where no matter what location I type into the dialog, it keeps saying

```
Audacity could not find a safe place to store temporary files.
Audacity needs a place where automatic cleanup programs won't delete the temporary files.
Please enter an appropriate directory in the preferences dialog.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you install audacity via the `snap` package manager, it does not work. It must be installed with `apt`

So the solution was

```
sudo snap remove audacity
sudo apt-get install audacity -y
```